# How to activate the background button again after clicking cancel?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

Consider the following code:

```
// Pause Button related code start
public function pauseTest( extReference:String,testID:String):void
{
    DetailsPanelView(view).pauseButton.enabled = false;
    var exeCompDO:PauseTestDO = new PauseTestDO(extReference,testID,"");
    if (exeCompDO != null)
    {
        send(new PauseCommentCue(exeCompDO));
    }
}

[CommandResult]
public function onPauseTestResult(result:ResultEvent, trigger:PauseTestTrigger):void
{
    //DetailsPanelView(view).pauseButton.enabled = true;
}

[CommandError]
public function onPauseTestError(error:FaultEvent, trigger:PauseTestTrigger):void
{
    //DetailsPanelView(view).pauseButton.enabled = true;
    TestUtility.showFaultEventReason(error,this);

}
```

When clicking on pause, a workflow pops up and allows me to add some comment. When I save it, the workflow closes and changes the status to paused.

But when I click the pause button and click anywhere on the screen or cancel the workflow, it saves to the draft but the background pause button still remains disable. After I click my selection again then the button enables.
I want it to enable right after I cancel the workflow. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give more context from your code? Also, you have commented out the line that would presumably re-enable the pause button, was that intentional?

Comment: Yeah, that was intentional, I was trying that but did not help.

Comment: Can I add a listener before or after sending the `PauseCommentCue` , so that the cancel button event can be listened?

Comment: Are the "pause button", "background pause button", and "background button" all the same button or different buttons? Your problem is difficult to understand. Please provide some more context on what's going on and maybe some more code outside of the above functions. If you're trying to enable the pause button, obviously it will never get enabled if the line that enables it is commented out

Comment: When I select a column and clcik pause button a workflow pops out, making the pause button disable util I click save, cancel or draft. If I click save it saves the comments in the workflow and saves it and changes the status to pause.
But when I click cancel, the workflow gets removed and the status remains the same, but the Pause button is not enabled again.

Comment: Workaround is to select some other column and the select the same column again to enable the pause button.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you can pass the **callback** function which enables the button, you can call that function on **Result** and **Error**.

**OR**

2) Use **binding** variable to **enable/disable** the button. If your *view* has *model*, define one property which you bind with **Enabled** property of the button. Then you can change that property of the *model* in **Result** and **Error**.